# Thunderbird: Adding new message recipient with the keyboard

Tags: keyboard, thunderbird

I'm trying to use Thunderbird using just the keyboard.

When creating a new message, I want to add another recipient row. I know I can click the field to add, but I want to do it with the keyboard. Possible?

Comment: I don't understand, just hit `<enter>`, TB will add the row for you. Does that not work?

Comment: You're right, I didn't try that. Feel free to add this as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply press the `<enter>` key and Thunderbird will add another row for you.